What options do I have if I'm able to buy more shares of a stock than the total supply?
I'm invested in a penny stock I think could increase in value. A bunch of other shareholders are fairly pessimistic about the stock believing it's being manipulated down by market makers. They believe no matter the demand the price will still be manipulated down. So, if I manage to buy more shares than the total supply who do I sue to get my money back?

If the stock is being actively manipulated by professionals, as many penny stocks are, chances are that you're going to lose a lot of money trying to beat them at their own game

Does it strike anyone as odd that the OP goes right to lawsuit as the solution?  The more likely scenario is the one Bob presents in his answer.

How could you buy more shares than there are? What money back?

If you somehow managed to buy more shares than exist, you will have created a paradox that will collapse the universe. Or, perhaps more likely, you have just been swindled.

I am involved in a lawsuit over MMATQ. What we need is investors to file their claims if we can get the total share count held 1 above the issued share count. Major banks owe the shareholders a few billion dollars. The problem is proving naked shorting is extremely difficult, and it is rampant through out the equity markets despite being illegal.

If you place an order for a penny stock and your broker fills the order, you will get the stock. The broker would not debit your account for shares not delivered. If the broker did charge you for shares he did  not deliver, you could sue him.
Here is a real problem with penny stocks. Suppose you are interested in the XYZ stock which has a current bid of $0.75 and an ask of $0.89. In addition it is thinly traded. Let say you  want two million shares so you place an order, with a limit price of $0.89$. It is very likely that you will only get a partial fill. That is, your buy order is affecting the market. You could raise the price you are willing to pay. You can buying the shares over a week, rather than all in one day.
Also, if you buy more than 5% of a public company you are going to need to file form SEC 13d.

Good answer.  To mitigate market influence, see "Icerberg orders" if your broker allows.

I've heard of people buying all of the shares of their company's stock, and the next day there's short sales of the stock, despite him not lending shares. If something like that happens who do I sue?

If someone owns all the shares then they own the company and nobody else can sell shares they don't own. It's quite unlikely, though, and requires quite a bit of paperwork.

The problem is synthetic shares exist, particularly when it comes to the OTC. So, even though I might own all of the actual shares some prop trading firm can still short my position from being connected.

Why do you think there is anybody to sue?
Suppose I go to the local supermarket to buy 1000 boxes of washing powder.  But they only have 50 in stock.  Who can I sue?  Nobody.  I can buy those 50 boxes, or not.
Similarly if you want to buy 1 million penny stock shares, but nobody is selling that many, then you simply can't buy them.  You can't force other shareholders to sell their shares to you.
If you have enough money to buy every share that comes up for sale, you may be able to create a short squeeze (GameStop was a good example of that).  But that's a high risk strategy, and you may need a lot of money to keep it up.

If you own all the shares in a company, anybody stupid enough to try naked short selling the shares is a golden opportunity for you to fleece them out of a large sum of money
Suppose they offer to sell 10000 shares at $0.10 each.  You know they don't really have them, and they need to find those shares to deliver them by close of business.  So you buy the shares they are selling.
You then wait, and watch them sweat as no shares come on to the market for them to deliver to you.
Then you offer 10000 shares for sale at £10.00 each.  They can either buy them, and you make a tidy $99000 profit.  Or they default, and their name as a stockbroker is trashed.

What I'm looking to do is buy every share. I then want to sue people if someone shorts the stock. Since I know no shares are available for shorting since I own every share. In other words who do I sue for manipulation?

@ZeroPhase Simon B already gave you the keywords "Short Squeeze" and "Gamestop". What you are looking for is exactly what happened there: Shortsellers had sold 140% of the existing shares. But this is not illegal on its own, they just had to pay a lot of money to get out of this. And you personally do no need to sue anyone, the Exchange (or rather their Settlement) would do that in case it is ever needed, as they are the ones that sold you the shares and are supposed to ensure you get those.

@ZeroPhase you don't sue anybody.

I'm asking if there's manipulation going on who I sue over that. Short selling is fine, as long as they're not artificially manipulating the price of a stock down. If there is naked shorting do I sue the brokers or the shorts engaged in it? My understanding is the practice is mostly illegal.

@SimonB I'm holding MMATQ, and the trustee has lawsuits against major banks. What's happening is shareholders who file their claim for the bankruptcy are getting harassed by some prop trader at the Merchandise Mart to frighten them into not filing their claim.
If we can prove one extra share exists that guy owes us billions easily. Not to mention major financial institutions as well.

@ZeroPhase looking at the finances, that company is not worth billions.

The company is not worth billions. If financial institutions enabled naked shorting, and the trustee can prove it. The payout is worth billions. I believe it happened since some guy running a fund is harassing people who file their shares for claims in the bankruptcy. We might be able to sue him to recoup money over him interfering with the bankruptcy process.

There's also some assets not listed on their books that could make this worth $1 to $2 per share within five years. They still have to figure out how much they get from liquidating divisions of the business prior to bankruptcy. That liquidation happened prior to filing, and those funds are not accounted for in the filing. I think the accounting was not done yet. There are also various lawsuits the trustee is bringing against different executives.
